# How to show progress indicator while scanning barcode

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        // appBar: AppBar(
        //   title: Text('Future Demo Page'),
        // ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
            // Checking if future is resolved or not
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // If we got an error
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '${snapshot.error} occured',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                );

                // if we got our data
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // Extracting data from snapshot object
                final data = snapshot.data as String;
                getGoodsData(data);
                // return getGoodsData(data);
              }
            }

            // Displaying LoadingSpinner to indicate waiting state
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },

          // Future that needs to be resolved
          // inorder to display something on the Canvas
          future: startBarcodeScanStream(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> startBarcodeScanStream() async {
    FlutterBarcodeScanner.getBarcodeStreamReceiver(
            '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE)
        .listen((barcode) {
      // if (!mounted) return;
      this.barcodeScanner = barcode;
      print(barcode);

      // Don't show form if barcode sacnner is cancelled
      if (barcode == "-1") {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    });

    return barcodeScanner;
  }
```

I am implementing barcode scanner in my flutter application. Once scanning is done I want to show progressIndicator at the center of scanning and I have to call the api.The above code is not showing any progress indicator.

Note: I want to show progressIndicator at the center of scanner after scanning and I have to call the api one response comes successfully I have to hide that progress indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add a new condition in your `FutureBuilder` that will detect that you are still waiting for the scan to complete and will display a loading until scan is done, then it will display normal widgets

**Code:**

```
 body: FutureBuilder(
   builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
      // This is new code: state NOT "done"
      if (snapshotGames.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
         return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());}
      }
      // The rest of your code is the same
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
```

Comment: i have tried with your code its not showing progress indicator for me

Comment: only the scaning is visible

Answer (score 0):

You should add a bool variable to control the progress indicator and a Stack to put widget in front.

```
//Add variable
bool _loading=false;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Stack(
         children:[
           Positioned(
            child: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
            // Checking if future is resolved or not
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // If we got an error
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '${snapshot.error} occured',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                );

                // if we got our data
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // Extracting data from snapshot object
                final data = snapshot.data as String;
                getGoodsData(data);
                // return getGoodsData(data);
              }
            }

            // Displaying LoadingSpinner to indicate waiting state
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },

          // Future that needs to be resolved
          // inorder to display something on the Canvas
          future: startBarcodeScanStream(),
        ),
      ),
           ),

         if(_loading==true) //show progress indicator if loading is true
         Positioned(
           child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(), 
           )
         )
         ]
     ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> startBarcodeScanStream() async {

    setState(() {_loading=true;}); //start showing Circular Progress Indicator
    FlutterBarcodeScanner.getBarcodeStreamReceiver(
            '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE)
        .listen((barcode) {
      // if (!mounted) return;
      this.barcodeScanner = barcode;
      print(barcode);

      // Don't show form if barcode sacnner is cancelled
      if (barcode == "-1") {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    });

    return barcodeScanner;
  }
```